# I'm trying to create a function that will take in one argument as a string, and delete that string from an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to create a function that will take in one argument as a string, and delete that string from an array. I've looked and tried 'remove(at:)' but this is not working. I need the function to take in the droid's name, and delete it from the array. It's so simple, but I can't find anything anywhere that would help. I keep finding things that specify a certain place in the array as an Int, but I need the function to work with a string.

```
var starWarsDroids: [String] = ["R2-D2", "C-3P0", "IG-88", "BB-8"]


func removeDroid(droid:String) {

    starWarsDroids.remove(at:0)
}


removeDroid(droid: "C-3P0")

print(starWarsDroids)
```

This is all I could come up with, and I know it doesn't work, so please don't tell me it doesn't. There has to be a way to do this without specifying a place in the array with an Int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
var starWarsDroids: [String] = ["R2-D2", "C-3P0", "IG-88", "BB-8"]

func removeDroid(droid:String) -> Bool {

    if let index = starWarsDroids.index(of: droid)  {

        starWarsDroids.remove(at: index)

        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: Why? You have already checked to see if the array contained that string, and if it does, it returns the index of that string for you to remove. You don't need to check if it has been removed because if it contained the string it gets removed.

Comment: @TristanBeaton iWheelBuy means that the `removeDroid` method should return a `Bool` to indicate whether the droid was removed or not.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! I knew it had to be something as simple as this. Thank you again Tristan!

Answer (score 1):

```
func removeDroid(droid: String) {
    starWarsDroids = starWarsDroids.filter{$0 != droid}
}
```